# Visual Studio/Angular - Argument of type is not assignable to parameter type ObjectIterateeCustom<any[], boolean>

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, lodash

I'm working on an angular 5 project using typescript 3.8.3 and loadash. I use Visual Studio Code as my editor. I've recently updated my Visual Studio Code to Version 1.24.0

Following the update I am getting some code syntax errors in visual studio code. These errors don't cause any compiler failures instead just show up as red in my code. One annoying one I am get is for the following code using loads:

```
let id: string = '122354';
let queue: any[] = records;
_.find(queue, {value: id}) // loads iteration function
```

My Error Message

```
Argument of type '{ value: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ObjectIterateeCustom<any[], boolean>'.
Type '{ value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ObjectIterator<any[], boolean>'.
Type '{ value: string; }' provides no match for the signature '(value: any, key: string, collection: any[]): boolean'.
```

Unfortunately I am not in the position to define queue with the value type. What are my options to remove this syntax error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[lodash's `find` method](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/underscore/index.d.ts) has a type definition like

```
find<T>(
        object: _.Dictionary<T>,
        iterator: _.ObjectIterator<T, boolean>,
        context?: any): T | undefined;
```

Notice the ObjectIterator's type `T`. That means that the object property(s)/value(s) passed to the iterator has to match the type passed as the `object` argument.

**In other words, `_.find(*[], {value: *, otherProp: *})` the asterisks must be the same type.**

Try

```
let id: any= '122354';
let queue: any[] = records;
_.find(queue, {value: id})
```

You could also add `as any` to the value. This casts the `id` to an `any` type, matching the type of `queue`.

```
let id: string = '122354';
let queue: any[] = records;
_.find(queue, {value: id as any})
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the structure of `queue` ?

`_.find(queue, {value: id})`

try replacing `{value: id}` with a function

```
const someFn = (el) => {
 return el.id === id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the type any, please try to put an interface with the property value

```
let queue: Record[] = [];
let record:Record=_.chain(queue).find({value:id}).value();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare the type parameter `T` explicitly, rather than allowing it to be inferred:

```
let id: string = '122354';
let queue: any[] = records;
_.find<string[]>(queue, {value: id});
```